# Where is this text in a wordpress email coming from? Want to change/remove

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I vaguely remember adding this text somehow ("Thank you for trying our product. We hope it brings you joy.") during some late night coding session. However, I've since forgot and want to remove it very much. I've looked all through the settings and can't find where it was added. Please advise!

[image: picture of my order complete email]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like an order note for the specific product. Check the order notes under advanced when editing the product.

Comment: Thank you, you were right.